# Referencing to python array slices and memory usage

Tags: python, arrays, memory

I would like to create multiple references to the same sequence of numbers. Can't use indexes, the data should be explicitly available as a sequence. The results is used later for read-only operations.

What i tried:

```
m = np.array([[199, 299,   3],[  4,   5,   6],[  7,   8,   9]])
a=m[1,]
```

I know that this supposed to copy:

```
a[:]
```

now if I try:

```
b=[]
for x in range(100000): b.append(a[:])
```

I get an about 16MB increase in memory usage (task manager)
Where:

```
for x in range(100000): b.append(a)
```

adds less than 1MB to used mem.

Anyway changing *a* or changing *a[:]* changes *m*. And *b* appears to be equal in both examples.

What is going on here, and what is the best way to reference the same row with minimum memory usage.

Comment: The problem is that each slice creates a new Python *object*,  a  `numpy.ndarray` object, but that object happens to share the same underlying buffer with `a`, but it still requires Python object overhead, which is on my Python 3.6 interpreter about 16 bytes. Otherwise, if you just use `a` you are *not* creating a new object, instead, you are simply appending a new reference, which takes up a machine-word's worth of memory (a pointer). So, on my 64-bit system this would be 8 bytes.

Comment: The most efficient way, then, to append multiple references to the same slice is to *only create a single array object*, so `my_slice = a[i, j]` then `for _ in range(N): b.append(my_slice)`

Comment: Note, that should be at *minimum* 16 bytes overhead for a new object, but it is likely more since a `numpy.ndarray` will have several attributes outside of the buffer itself. So a good guesstimate would be `sys.getsizeof(np.array([]))` which for me returns `96` bytes